# Spinner selecting Items even if the dropdown is open

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my app with custom adapter. The issue that I am facing is : while opening the spinner dropdown and just closing it without selecting any item, even if I am not selecting any spinner item, the first spinner item is getting selected.

So, in simple words just after simply opening and closing the spinner dropdown without selecting any item , if I am calling `spinner.getselecteditem.getText.toString`, it returns the first spinner item.

Below I am posting my code:

on button press:

```
CustomSpinnerAdapterVertical customSpinnerAdapterVerticalMarket = new CustomSpinnerAdapterVertical(myContext,
                    R.layout.vertical_spinner_row, alst_verticalMarket, "Select Vertical Market");
            vertical_spinner.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapterVerticalMarket);
```

For the CustomSpinnerAdapterVertical:

```
class CustomSpinnerAdapterVertical extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> objects;
String firstElement;
boolean isFirstTime;

public CustomSpinnerAdapterVertical(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects, String defaultText) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.isFirstTime = true;
    setDefaultText(defaultText);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(isFirstTime) {
        objects.set(0, firstElement);
        isFirstTime = false;
    }
    return getCustomDropdownView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
    this.firstElement = objects.get(0);
    objects.set(0,defaultText);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical_spinner_row, parent, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
    label.setText(objects.get(position));

    return row;
}
public View getCustomDropdownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_vertical_item, parent, false);
    CheckedTextView label = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    label.setText(objects.get(position));


    return row;
}

}
```

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Its spinner default behaviour. By default select first item

Comment: add first item as empty string

Comment: @shohel : I need to make sure that user is selecting a data before going to next screen. Presently Its showing just "select item" while the first item is returning in getselectedItem(). is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: @AnimeshJena You need to check durring go to next screen. 

Example :

String  value=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("select item")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please select your item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            // Goto next screen
        }